# How to Change Y axis on a pandas dataframe plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list:

```
[('und', 52),
 ('die', 36),
 ('von', 33),
 ('der', 29),
 ('in', 20),
 ('das', 17),
 ('für', 17),
 ('eine', 15),
 ('des', 14),
 ('Die', 14),
 ('ODP', 14),
 ('wurde', 13),
 ('zu', 13)]
```

With the following code I convert it to a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_by_value, columns=['Wort', 'Vorkommen'])
```

Then I plot it:

```
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(1,1)  # a figure with a 2x2 grid of Axes
df10 = df[:20]
df10.Vorkommen.plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

How can I change the y axis from the index to the words?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `plot.barh` uses the index. You can explicitly set the x and y values like so:

```
df.plot.barh(x='Wort', y='Vorkommen')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
`Pandas` will use the index of your `DataFrame` as your labels by default.

```
df10.set_index('Wort').Vorkommen.plot(kind='barh')
```